# XSLT - More than one validation

Tags: validation, xslt

I am not a programmer and need some help from the pros. If I have more than one validation I want to check for exampel I want this result when test = 78 or 81 otherwise.

I have tried using without succcess

```
<xsl:variable name = "vatTerm">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(DocumentXML/ApplicationObject/Object/CarTypeId!='78') and (CarTypeId!='81')">
      <xsl:value-of select="(($netterm+$termfee)*$vatrate )+$eptermfeetotalvat"/> 
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select ="$eptermfeetotalvat"/> 
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Also tried;

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="(DocumentXML/ApplicationObject/Object/CarTypeId!=78">
    <xsl:value-of select="(($netterm+$termfee)*$vatrate )+$eptermfeetotalvat"/> 
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="(DocumentXML/ApplicationObject/Object/CarTypeId!=81">
      <xsl:value-of select="(($netterm+$termfee)*$vatrate )+$eptermfeetotalvat"/> 
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select ="$eptermfeetotalvat"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Please post a complete example, we can't really know what's not working in your code without seeing what your input is.

Comment: *"I want this result when test = 78 or 81 otherwise."* I don't know what that means.

Comment: The code was working when I only had to check for "78", but it stopped working when I had to add "81" as a validation, Now it has to check if 78 or 81 and return a result, otherwise a different result. . I just need help with how to input more than 1 validation in the same code?

Comment: We need to see your input (for example, is there only one `CarTypeId` in the document, or several) and we need to understand better exactly what condition you are testing for. Since you appear to be inexperienced in use of boolean logic, you might find it easiest to explain by example: show examples of elements that should, or should not, be selected.

Comment: You do the opposite of what you when . You should test when = 78 do something, when 81 do something, otherwise do something else. Your second try can’t run because in the first when you eliminate cases that would match the second when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the [DeMorgan](https://wikiless.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws?lang=en) right.
But you forgot that the path's base is not duplicated. So, I guess, you should try

```
<xsl:when test="DocumentXML/ApplicationObject/Object/CarTypeId!='78' and DocumentXML/ApplicationObject/Object/CarTypeId!='81'">
  <xsl:value-of select="(($netterm+$termfee)*$vatrate )+$eptermfeetotalvat"/> 
</xsl:when>
```

This approach has the restriction that it checks if **any** `CarTypeId` at the given path is unequal to 78 or 81. If you have only one `CarTypeId`, this will be working fine with XPath-1.0.

With XPath-2.0 you could simplify and precise this task.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the one predicate like this

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="DocumentXML/ApplicationObject/Object/CarTypeId[.!='78' and .!='81']">
    <xsl:value-of select="(($netterm+$termfee)*$vatrate )+$eptermfeetotalvat"/> 
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select ="$eptermfeetotalvat"/> 
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: What does `.!='81'` mean, when we don't know the context?